# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have tab bar with 2 elements, they both have same menu `NewMenu`. I want hide menu on 1st tab bar, when user open menu on 2th tab bar and vice versa.

This I use in 1st tab bar:

```
    func hideMenuOnSurveyList() {
        let surveyListNC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![1] as! UINavigationController
        guard surveyListNC.viewControllers.count > 1, surveyListNC.viewControllers[1] is NewMenu else {
            return
        }
        surveyListNC.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    }
```

And this in 2th tab bar:

```
func hideMenuOnNewsList() {
        let newsListNC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
        guard newsListNC.viewControllers.count > 1, newsListNC.viewControllers[1] is NewMenu else {
            return
        }
        newsListNC.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    }
```

And they both give out this issue:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions
```

I also try use `DispatchQueue.main.async`, put this into `ViewDidAppear`, set `(animated: false)` but this doesn't work in my case